# Typescript does not seem to work, no errors in code but component does not display

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, json, typescript, angular

I have done a small test angular2 application with typescript. I do not have any errors but my generated js file is not loading. Here is my code;

in default.aspx page I have my selector:

```
 <asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderID="PlaceHolderMain" runat="server">
 <app-main>Loading...</app-main>
 </asp:Content>
```

boot.ts

```
import {bootstrap} from 'angular2/platform/browser'
import {AppComponent} from './app.component'
bootstrap(AppComponent)
```

app.component.ts

```
import {Welcome} from './app.module'
import {Component} from 'angular2/core'
@Component({
selector: 'app-main',
template: `<h1>${Welcome.GetWelcome()}</h1>`
}) export class AppComponent { }
```

app.module.ts

```
export class Welcome {
static GetWelcome(): string {
    return "Hello World";
}
}
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
"compileOnSave": true,
"compilerOptions": {
"watch":  true,
"noImplicitAny": false,
"noEmitOnError": true,
"removeComments": false,
"sourceMap": true,
"target": "ES5",
"module": "system",
"moduleResolution": "node",
"emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
"experimentalDecorators": true
 },
 "exclude": [
 "./node_modules",
 "./typings/main",
 "./typings/main.d.ts"
 ]
 }
```

The code is compiling but the Welcome message is not loading in the app-main. What am I doing wrong here? I am working with Visual Studio 2015, Version 14.0

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's not how you bind a string from a controller in a view in angular2. :)

Answer (score 3):

I've made a plunkr for you http://plnkr.co/edit/oMOvCgFzqtnYYPcE2U6j?p=preview

As @toskv suggested binding a string does not work like that. You define the string as a field in your component. And use it with double `{{msg}}` tags in your template. Here's the short version:

```
@Component({
selector: 'app-main',
template: `<h1>{{msg}}</h1>`
}) 
export class AppComponent {
  msg = Welcome.GetWelcome();      
}
```

Comment: Thank  you for making a plunker for me, but the code still does not work in my Visual Studio version, no errors so.

Comment: yes I have implemented your code but my visual studio version still does not work

Comment: With not working I mean the welcome message within <app-main> </app-main>is not displaying

Comment: @leokadia how/where are you configuring systemjs to load the application? You seem to have left that out in your question. Or maybe you haven't configured it at all and the code is just not loaded? :P

Comment: I have a tsconfig.json file

Comment: {
    "compileOnSave": true,
   "compilerOptions": {
     "watch":  true,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "noEmitOnError": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "ES5",
    "module": "system",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true
      },
       "exclude": [
        "./node_modules",
       "./typings/main",
       "./typings/main.d.ts"
     ]
    }

Comment: @leokadia you also need a systemjs config. Check the plunkr index.html

Comment: <script>
         System.config({ packages: { './scripts': { format: 'register', defaultExtension: 'js' } } });
         System.import('./scripts/boot').then(null, console.error.bind(console));
     </script>

Comment: @leokadia What happens when you just change your template with `template: '<h1>Hello World!</h1>'` does it display?

Comment: The code does not seem to load my component but even in debug mode I do not get any errors

Comment: Is your boot.ts and app.component.ts in the same directory?